# How to add border to fill listview row

Tags: android, listview

I wish to add a border to each `listview` item, but it look like so ugly.
So how can I make all border to fill the height of the row?

Here is the picture

[image]

Here is my `listview` item

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:maxEms="5"
        android:minEms="5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:background="@drawable/corner3"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:maxEms="5"
        android:minEms="5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:background="@drawable/corner3"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Listview

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listVie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            >

        </ListView>
```

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at first put items in a linear layout and then change the height of textviews to match the height of most left textView